# What is the distribution of Y=n-x?

Tags: probability

If X has the binomial distribution with parameters n and p. What is the distribution of Y=n-X?

My guess is it is binomial, but I'm not quite sure about this. 
Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  If $X$ is the number of successes from $n$ trials, what is $n-X$?

Comment: That would be the number of failures. So, maybe the probability of P(X=x) = 1 - P(Y=n-x)? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: So, turn it around and say that "success" now counts as "failure" and vice versa.  What is now the distribution of failures?  And what are the numerical parameters involved?

Comment: Wouldn't you do $n\choose {n-X}$ instead of $n\choose x$ When you work it out though you get ${n\choose {n-X}}={n\choose x}$ I think.

Comment: but it would change the right side of the p.d.f too.

Comment: Don't do algebra, think about what sort of experiment you are doing.

Comment: So failures have binomial distribution, with parameters n and n-p. Is that alright?

Comment: Parameters $n$, the number of trials, and $1-p$, the probability of "success" (failure in the original experiment).  I assume $n-p$ was a typo ;-)